# How to detect if function was the last to be called

Tags: javascript, function, parsing, functional-programming

I have to make a mathematical expressions' evaluator by using functions like add, subtract, cnst (stands for constant) or variable which take one or two arguments, depends on what kind of operation we need: unary or binary. Here's an example of what I am talking about:

```
let expression = add(cnst(2), add(cnst(2), variable("x")));
```

Expression must be a function, so we can just call `expression(3)` and have our result: 7.

My idea is to return a string representation of number or variable, if it's about constant or variable and return a string concatenation of first argument, operation and second argument if it's about binary operation. But, we need to make the result a function. So, I thought it would be nice to return a function:

```
evaluate(x) {
    return eval(expr);
}
```

if **this call was last**. I mean, in the example above all internal functions should return '2', '2', 'x', '2+x' but the external one (add) should return 'evaluate' and set the global value 'expr' to what's needed in this context ('2+2+x'). So, is it possible to detect whether the external 'add' was called after all other functions?

Comment: The problem is not clear at all. And it seems like an homework.

Comment: It's for my understanding the fp paradigm. Problem is to edit each function in the way we can detect if this call is external (or last), to make it return a function, not a string in only this case.

Comment: In `expression(3)`, how does the function know that `3` is the value for the variable named `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tricky, but if you use `Object.defineProperty()` to redefine a function's expected `arguments.length`, you can return a function at every level and check its length value to determine whether the operand requires variables or not:

```js
function consume(vars) {
  return (arg) => arg(...vars.splice(0, arg.length));
}

function op(f) {
  return (...args) => {
    return Object.defineProperty((...vars) => {
      return f(...args.map(consume(vars)));
    }, 'length', {
      value: args.reduce((a, b) => a + b.length, 0)
    });
  };
}

const add = op((a, b) => a + b);
const sub = op((a, b) => a - b);
const cnst = (v) => () => v;
const variable = () => (v) => v;

let e1 = add(cnst(2), add(cnst(2), variable("x")));
let e2 = add(cnst(5), sub(variable("x"), variable("y")));

console.log(e1(5)); // 2 + (2 + 5)
console.log(e2(6, 3)); // 5 + (6 - 3)
```

The downside is that you cannot specify arguments via labels with this approach. To do that, you can pass an object as a parameter to the expression instead:

```js
const op = (f) => (...args) => (o = {}) => f(...args.map(arg => arg(o)));

const add = op((a, b) => a + b);
const sub = op((a, b) => a - b);
const cnst = (v) => () => v;
const variable = (label) => (o) => o[label];

let e1 = add(cnst(2), add(cnst(2), variable("x")));
let e2 = add(cnst(5), sub(variable("x"), variable("y")));

console.log(e1({ x: 5 })); // 2 + (2 + 5)
console.log(e2({ x: 6, y: 3 })); // 5 + (6 - 3)
```

And finally, if you want an interop where you can specify args to a function like normal and have them mapped to variable names, you can add another expression type called `args()` that defines the mapping like so:

```js
const op = (f) => (...args) => (o = {}) => f(...args.map(arg => arg(o)));

const args = (map) => (e) => (...args) => e(map(...args));
const add = op((a, b) => a + b);
const sub = op((a, b) => a - b);
const cnst = (v) => () => v;
const variable = (label) => (o) => o[label];

let a1 = args(x => ({ x }));
let e1 = a1(add(cnst(2), add(cnst(2), variable("x"))));

let a2 = args((x, y) => ({ x, y }));
let e2 = a2(add(cnst(5), sub(variable("x"), variable("y"))));

console.log(e1(5)); // 2 + (2 + 5)
console.log(e2(6, 3)); // 5 + (6 - 3)
```

Comment: This is really nice of you, I found it very helpful.